# JPA - EntityListener - @PrePersist and @PreUpdate work successfully, but @PostPersist and @PostUpdate not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitylisteners

Possible Duplicated

I have this weird bug in my Java Desktop Application, when i use **@PrePersist** and **@PreUpdate** all the code from the callback methods is executed, but when i use **@PostPersist** and **@PostUpdate** only the `System.out.println(...)` code is executed.

Here's my code:

**Entity -> Area**

```
import com.pete.bibliogere.modelo.listeners.EntidadeOperacoes;
import com.pete.bibliogere.modelo.listeners.EntidadeOperacoesInterface;

@Entity
@Table(name = "areas")
@EntityListeners(value = EntidadeOperacoes.class)
public class Area implements Serializable, EntidadeOperacoesInterface {

    @Column(updatable = false, name = "data_registo")
    private LocalDate dataRegisto;

    @Column(name = "data_alteracao")
    private LocalDate dataAlteracao;

... Some Getters, Setters and other attributes omited...

@Override
    public void setDataRegisto(LocalDate data_registo) {
        this.data_registo = data_registo;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataAlteracao(LocalDate data_alteracao) {
        this.data_alteracao = data_alteracao;
    }
}
```

**Interface for Entities to share the same external EntityListener**

```
public interface EntidadeOperacoesInterface {

    public void setDataRegisto(LocalDate data_registo);

    public void setDataAlteracao(LocalDate data_alteracao);
}
```

**External EntityListener -> EntidadeOperacoes**

```
public class EntidadeOperacoes {

    @PostPersist
    public void antesRegistar(EntidadeOperacoesInterface entidade) {
        System.out.println("-------- Inserindo data Inserção ------");
        entidade.setDataRegisto(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println("-------- Fim Inserção ------");

    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void depoisAlteracao(EntidadeOperacoesInterface entidade) {
        System.out.println("-------- Data Atualização ------");
        entidade.setDataAlteracao(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println("-------- Fim ------");

    }
```

**AreaController**

```
public final class AreaController {

   private EntityManager em;
   private Validator validator;
   private AreaDao dao;

   public void registar(String nome, String localizacao) {
       validator = ValidatorUtil.getValidator();
       em = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

       em.getTransaction().begin();
       dao = new AreaServico(em, validator);
       dao.registar(new Area(nome.trim(), localizacao.trim()));
       em.getTransaction().commit();

       em.close();
       ValidatorUtil.close();
   }

   public void alterar(long codigo, String nome, String localizacao) {
       validator = ValidatorUtil.getValidator();
       em = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

       em.getTransaction().begin();
       dao = new AreaServico(em, validator);
       dao.atualizar(new Area(codigo, nome, localizacao));
       em.getTransaction().commit();

       em.close();
       ValidatorUtil.close();

   }

// Testing Purposes
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       AreaController ac = new AreaController();

       // Persiste area
       ac.registar("Area 1", "Localização 1");
   }
```

**AreaServico -> Service Class*

```
public class AreaServico implements AreaDao {

    private EntityManager em;
    private Validator validator;

    public AreaServico(EntityManager em, Validator validator) {
        this.em = em;
this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void registar(Area area) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Area>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(area);

        if (constraintViolations.iterator().hasNext()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage(), "Atenção!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            if (areaExiste(area.getNome())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: A área digitada já existe."
                        + "\nCertifique-se de escolher outro nome!", "Area existente!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                em.persist(area);
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void atualizar(Area area) {
        Area areaEncontrada = em.find(Area.class, area.getCodigo());
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Area>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(area);

        if (areaEncontrada != null) {
            if (constraintViolations.iterator().hasNext()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
            } else {
                if (areaExiste(area.getCodigo(), area.getNome())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: Já existe uma área com este nome.\n"
                            + "Certifique-se de escolher um nome diferente!", "Area existente!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    areaEncontrada.setNome(area.getNome());
                    areaEncontrada.setLocalizacao(area.getLocalizacao());
                }
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: A área digitada não existe!");
        }
    }
```

Here's the console log when i execute the Main method above

```
Handling #sessionFactoryCreated from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@37b52340] for TypeConfiguration

    select
        area0_.codigo as codigo1_0_,
        area0_.data_alteracao as data_alt2_0_,
        area0_.data_registo as data_reg3_0_,
        area0_.localizacao as localiza4_0_,
        area0_.nome as nome5_0_ 
    from
        areas area0_ 
    where
        upper(area0_.nome)=?
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [AREA 1]

    insert 
    into
        areas
        (data_alteracao, data_registo, localizacao, nome) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [null]
binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [null] /* This shouldn't be null, but LocalDate.now() */
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Localização 1]
binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Area 1]
Depois de Inserir registo - Inicio: 1934663431---
Depois de Inserir registo - Fim:1934663440---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  6.344 s
Finished at: 2020-10-29T09:44:24+02:00
```

Here's my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pete</groupId>
    <artifactId>BiblioGere</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `updatable = false` on dataRegisto field so it seems normal the setter doesn't update the value in database.

@PostUpdate is called after fulshing the session.
Could you try to add :

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

And after calling update :

```
entityManager.flush();
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you @Gweltaz Niquel , this fixed the PostPersist problem, now the other problem is with the PostUpdate

Comment: I don't see where you flush the session.

Comment: When i use em.flush(), it works successfully, but my question now is, is it recommended to use the flush() method?

Comment: You should use flush when you want data to be persisted in database in your program. It depends of your session (What you want to do before asking database to effectively store) and yes It should be called when needed (for example because you know that your program will need to read it soon or even you don't know when...) even if at one time database will do it herself depending on your database tunning but it's not a really good parctice to wait for it...

Comment: I still don't understand why PreUpdate gets called even though i don't use em.flush, but PostUpdate gets called only when i use em.flush

Comment: Sorry it seems obvious : preUbdate is called immediately because no matter when the update is triggered It have to be fired.
PostUpdate is fired only when an update is triggered then either you wait for it and it will be called one time or you make it update using flush (who tell to put memory changes to database storage). You can for example try to reboot your database nicely : it will also trigger the postUpdate even if you didn"t called flush()

Comment: So the PostUpdate is triggered only when the data is sent from the PersistenceContext to the Database Table, right? that's why the callback method wasn't executed?

Comment: Exactly : It depends on the database update, not the program... (Until you explicitly ask to do it).